# What version of apc (or php) is the APCIterator class available?

Tags: php, apc, pecl

I'm trying to use the APCIterator class, and on a number of system configurations I'm getting a `Fatal Error: class 'APCIterator' not found` error.

I've tried:

- Fedora 11, PHP 5.2.13, APC 3.0.19
- Centos 5, PHP 5.2.14, APC 3.1.4
- Windows 7, PHP 5.2.7, APC 3.0.19

APC is installed correctly and working fine using the apc_store() and apc_fetch() methods, just the APCIterator class is causing problems.

There's very little documentation on when the class was introduced, and which version of APC/PHP it comes with. The best I can find is a comment in the changelog on the PECL site suggesting APCIterator was introduced in [APC 3.1.1](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=APC)

Can anyone tell me if there's something I need to install, or a version I need to upgrade to to use this?

Comment: On linux machines, you can run `pecl install apc` to download and compile the newest version. You will need a compiler and any php devel packages installed.

Comment: If you have Zend Server CE you need to disable the APC Compatability Extensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was getting the same error on APC 3.1.9 and 3.1.7.

It turns out it only works if you put `apc.enable_cli=1` in your php.ini!

Comment: I'm seeing this same error and have this setting set with no apparent change.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation at php.net says (looking at the `__construct()`-Method), that it's available in PECL-apc-versions >= 3.1.1.

See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/apciterator.construct.php